# Select line on the map and check its attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In QGIS can I select a line in the map and check its attributes?

I have an ESRI shape file but I am not able to select or choose any line of the map in QGIS, I see, it looks like one block but in show attribute table, I see lots of different id.

When I show attributes in the table and select any id, QGIS should show me which line belongs to this id on the map, right?

I am totally new and I need to have good start in it.

Comment: Please edit your question to use proper grammar, sentences and capitalisation. Use the "Identify Features" tool - which looks like an `(i)` in a blue circle. Make sure the layer from which you want to identify features is selected in the table of contents.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree that a good start is crucial for successful working with QGIS.

First of all, select your line layer in the layer tree:

[image]

Then you can either:

- use the **Identify tool**

[image]

...and click on your desired line. It will turn red, and a window with the features attributes (ok, few in this example...) appears:

[image]

- with one of the **Select features** tools

[image]

you can select one or more features of the selected layer. These turn yellow in the map and in the status line you can see the number of selected features of the layer:

[image]

Then open the attribute table of the layer and at the bottom left select **Show selected features**, which should be self-explaining.

- The opposite way works too. Select one or more features in the attribute table and click on **Zoom to selection**, either in the QGIS main window or in the attribute table.

[image]

- Furthermore you can right-click a feature in the attribute table and select from one of the options **Zoom to Feature**, **Pan to Feature** and **Flash Feature**

[image]

**SIDENOTE**

I think you'll have guessed it already: This answer is not specific to linestrings, but works with points and polygons too!

Comment: If you find this helpful, you can consider to accept this answer (click the 'v' right beneath the votes) ;-)